# Do I need a Facebook approval for releasing public application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-app-requests, facebook-permissions

Let's quote the documentation first:

> We will review how apps use Facebook Login: Apps requesting more than
>   public_profile, email and the user_friends permission must be reviewed
>   by Facebook before those permissions can be requested from people.
>   **Active apps created before April 30th, 2014 have one year before they
>   are required to go through login review, including updates to existing
>   apps.** Facebook apps created after April 30th, 2014 must go through
>   review.

So my application meets two statements:

- it was created before April 30th, 2014
- it requires the following permissions: `email`, `user_friends`, `publish_actions`, `user_birthday`, `friends_birthday`

**My application was never submitted for review before.**

The question is: do I need to go through FB review process or not **if I want to go public**?

From the one side my app satisfies creation data to "avoid" approval, but on the other hand it requires more than these "standard" permissions.

Comment: If you created the app before 4/30/2014 you only need to get the permissions approved by 4/30/2015

Comment: Don't exactly understand `…you only need to get the permissions approved by…`. So do I need to go through submission process or not?

Comment: Not before you go public. But if the permissions are not approved by 4/30/2015 you will not be able to ask users for that permission

Comment: OK, I updated my question. I want to go public and my app was never been reviewed yet.

Comment: Then just go live. But you will need to get it reviewed before 4/30/2015. But that can happen while the app is live

Comment: So what is this review process required for?

Comment: If you created you app after 4/30/2014 you would have to get it reviewed before taking it live. We are just giving old apps some time to get reviewed